# Under which sub-field of neuroscience can this project be best classified?

Tags: neuroscience, terminology

Under which subfield of neuroscience does a project that develops a deep learning model to study long-term brain scans of Alzheimer's caregivers and draw a correlation between staying in the proximity of Alzheimer's patients and the effects it has on the brain structure fall?

Answer (score 1):

I would say [Brain Imaging](https://www.nature.com/subjects/brain-imaging) or [Neuroimaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroimaging), although each of these terms can be regarded [as a group of methods](https://psychcentral.com/lib/types-of-brain-imaging-techniques) instead of a subfield of Neuroscience. However, because the field has exploded since (f)MRI was developed, the discipline of Brain Imaging has its own [journals](https://www.humanbrainmapping.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=3308) and [conferences](https://conferenceindex.org/conferences/brain-imaging). So I would suggest **Brain Imaging** or **Neuroimaging**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would fall under the field of [Social Neuroscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_neuroscience).

> Still a young field, social neuroscience is closely related to affective neuroscience and cognitive neuroscience, focusing on how the brain mediates social interactions.<sup>[5]</sup>
>
> <sup>[5]</sup> John T. Cacioppo; Gary G. Berntson; Jean Decety (2010). Social neuroscience and its relation to social psychology. *Social Cognition. 28*(6): 675–685. https://doi.org/10.1521/soco.2010.28.6.675. PMC [3883133](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3883133).

Quoting from the cited reference above,

> Although investigations of the role of biological factors can be found in social psychology ([Cacioppo, Petty, & Tassinary, 1989](https://richardepetty.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/1989-advances-cacioppopettytassinary.pdf)), the field has emphasized the role of situational factors and, in collaboration with personality theorists, the role of dispositional factors. Because the focus of both is social behavior, social psychology and social neuroscience have the potential to be aligned and thereby potentially inform constructs and theories in each (Berntson & Cacioppo, 2008). The emphasis in each is sufficiently different that neither field is in danger of being reduced to or replaced by the other, but articulating the different levels of analysis can provide a better understanding of complex social phenomena.

### References

Berntson, G. G., & Cacioppo, J. T. (2008). *Handbook of motivation science*. Guilford Press ISBN: 978-1593855680

Cacioppo, J. T., Petty, R. E., & Tassinary, L. G. (1989). Social psychophysiology: A new look. In *Advances in experimental social psychology* (Vol. 22, pp. 39-91). Academic Press. [Free PDF](https://richardepetty.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/1989-advances-cacioppopettytassinary.pdf)